# Moongose array indexOf doesn't finish running

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am trying to use Mongoose Array indexOf to check if an id is in an array of reference objects of another schema.

The following is the schema. The mongoose array is dishes.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var favoriteSchema = new Schema({
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    dishes: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Dish'
        }
    ]
}, {
    timestamps: true
});

var Favorites = mongoose.model('Favorite', favoriteSchema);

module.exports = Favorites;
```

The issue is on the line

```
if (favorites.dishes.indexOf(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.dishId)) === -1){
```

The line is in the following express router

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
var authenticate = require('../authenticate');
const cors = require('./cors');

const Favorites = require('../models/favorite');
const Dishes = require('../models/dishes');

const favoriteRouter = express.Router();

favoriteRouter.use(bodyParser.json());

favoriteRouter.route('/:dishId')
.post(authenticate.verifyUser, (req, res, next) => {
    if(mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(req.params.dishId)) {
        //Dishes.findById(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.dishId))
        Dishes.findById(req.params.dishId)
        .then((dish) => {
            if (dish != null) {
                //console.log("dish: ", dish);
                Favorites.findOne({user: req.user._id})
                .then((favorites) => {
                    //console.log("favorite: ", favorites);
                    if (favorites != null){
                        //favorites = favorites[0];
                        console.log("**1", favorites.dishes);
                        if (favorites.dishes.indexOf(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.dishId)) === -1){
                            console.log("**1");
                            favorites.dishes.push(req.params.dishId);
                            favorites.save()
                            .then((favorites) => {
                                res.statusCode = 200;
                                res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                                res.json(favorites);
                            }, (err) => next(err))
                            .catch((err) => next(err));
                        } //Error not returned if it is already in the list.
                    }else{
                        Favorites.create({user: req.user._id})
                        .then((favorites) => {
                            favorites.dishes.push(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.dishId));
                            favorites.save()
                            .then((favorites) => {
                                res.statusCode = 200;
                                res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                                res.json(favorites);
                            }, (err) => next(err))
                        }, (err) => next(err))
                        .catch((err) => next(err));
                    }
                }, (err) => next(err))
                .catch((err) => next(err));
            }else {
                err = new Error('Dish ' + req.params.dishId + ' is not in the database.');
                err.status = 404;
                return next(err);
            }

        }, (err) => next(err))
        .catch((err) => next(err));
    }else{
        err = new Error('Dish ' + req.params.dishId + ' is not in the database.');
        err.status = 404;
        return next(err);
    }

});

module.exports = favoriteRouter;
```

How can I solve the issu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the casting for the objectId, do it like this

```
favorites.dishes.indexOf(req.params.dishId === -1)
```

And if you want to return an error if it's already exist you should add an else block, to throw the error.

Also I suggest that you can write your code using `async/await` syntax it will be much cleaner than nested promises.

https://javascript.info/async-await